# setting the value of a variable in such equation to have a specific output

Tags: linear-algebra, signal-processing

Assume I have, for example, $x = 0.7 + 0.7i$ and the equation as below:
$$\tag{1}
(0.5+0.5i)y + (0.5 - 0.5i)x = 0
$$

in that case $y$ has the same magnitude of $x$. At the same time, if we swap $x$ and $y$ in  equation $(1)$, we will also have the same magnitude of $x$ and $y$. By this I mean to make the equation as:
$$
(0.5+0.5i)x + (0.5-0.5i)y = 0
$$
Now, if we have changed the above equation into:
$$\tag{2}
(0.5+0.5i)y + (0.5-0.5i)x = 0.5
$$
It means the $0$ becomes a constant such as $0.5$, What should be $x$ and $y$ in function of the constant $0.5$ in order to keep the property of first equation, which is having the same magnitude for $x$ and $y$ in both cases of  keeping them as it is or swapping them?.

Comment: Do you mean the **magnitude** (instead of amplitude)? Because in the first equation, setting $x=0.7+0.7i$ yields $y=-0.7+0.7i$, which has the same magnitude but different argument (you know, the angle ... )

Comment: Yes, it's magnitude,  sorry for that mistake, I will correct it.

Comment: So you're looking at equations of the form
$$\tag{1}
(0.5+0.5i) y + (0.5 - 0.5i) x = C
$$
and
$$\tag{2}
(0.5+0.5i) x + (0.5 - 0.5i) y = C
$$
that both have the requirement $|x|=|y|$. Your question is: "what are the values of $x$ and $y$". But do you require that those values fulfill the two equations **at the same time**, or is it two different questions, one for (1) and another for (2) ? This is still unclear to me.

Comment: Yes, You are right. . . I require that those values fulfill the two equations at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You previously had 0.5y + 0.5x = 0 and 0.5i*y - 0.5i*x = 0

Now you have (1+i)*y + (1-i)*x = 1
Hence x+y = 1 and i*y - i*x = 0

In both cases it guarantees x and y to have the same magnitude.

This is also symmetric set of equations, however if you want to keep the same magnitude, then you enforce x and y to have the same real argument equals 0.5

This is a bit intuitive since you change real argument on RHS.

Comment: thank you for your response, but I couldn't get what you mean!  Could you please explain more? and what you mean by RHS.

Comment: RHS is right hand side. So what I meant by that is that you changed 0.5 (real argument) is makes sense that you restrict your solutions to a particular solutions with some real argument.

Comment: So what should we  have the values of $x$ and $y$?  could you please explain it for me with an example if possible? .. when having x and y to have the same real argument equals to 0.5, is the 0.5 is the constant I provided in my question,  for example if it's 0.7,  that should be 0.7 too ?

Comment: still waiting for your clarification, please.